# python pandas compare two columns and return results

Tags: python, string, pandas, dataframe, comparison

I have two dataframes as below. I added `key` column to both so that I can get Cartesian joint. I want to compare each value from `df3` data frame's `BEN_NAME2` column with df4 data frames's `names2` column. My original plan was to perform Cartesian joint and to check whether there are any matching values. But both of my data frames are quite big and I am getting a memory error when I try to  join.

I would like to do this operation one cell at a time from the column `BEN_NAME2`. I would like to create a new column in `df3` which would give me row index from `df3` if the exact match was found.

For example, `df3` will get two new columns, column `match` with values `(0,1,0)` and column `matching_row_index` with values `(0,3,0)` because `jones` value from the second row has a match in the `df4` data frame

```
sales = [{'key': 0, 'BEN_NAME2': '150 jones'},
         {'key': 0,  'BEN_NAME2': 'jones'},
         {'key': 0,  'BEN_NAME2': '50'}]
df3 = pd.DataFrame(sales)

sales = [{'key': 0, 'names2': 'xyc'},
         {'key': 0,  'names2': 'fsdfa'},
         {'key': 0,  'names2': 'jones'}]
df4 = pd.DataFrame(sales)
```

## my main goal is get output at a relatively fast rate.

Answer (score 0):

Use `iloc()` in loop. This function allows you to navigate a data frame like an array.

```
for i in range(0,10):
    A=df['Ben_names'].iloc[i]
    B= df['column_name'].iloc[i]
    #write the conditional statement using if and value to be inserted is var

    df.['column_nmae2'].iloc[i]=var
```

Comment: I need to search ben name in the entire column of second dataframe...as of now your code seems to provide comparison just to one row